# How to use async tricks to handle IO and CPU mixed bound task in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

The background of the problem is to read data from a stream(IO-bound), process the data(CPU bound) then write to another stream(IO-bound).

The naive way is like this

```
thread 1: loop { |<--read data block from stream-->|<--process data block-->|<--write to stream-->| }
```

A naive producer-consumer pattern

```
thread 1: loop { |<--read data block from stream-->| enqueue data block to blocking queue A }

thread 2: loop { dequeue data block from blocking queue A |<--process data block-->| enqueue data block to blocking queue B }

thread 3: loop { dequeue data block from blocking queue B |<--write to stream-->| }
```

A stream example is as following

```
var hasher = MD5.Create();
using (FileStream readStream = new FileStream("filePath", FileMode.Open))
using (BufferedStream readBs = new BufferedStream(readStream ))
using (CryptoStream md5HashStream = new CryptoStream(readBs, hasher, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
using (FileStream writeStream= File.OpenWrite("destPath"))
using (BufferedStream writeBs = new BufferedStream(writeStream))
{
    md5HashStream.CopyTo(writeBs);
}
```

How to use C# async tricks such as async stream, channel, dataflow to transform the above stream sample to a producer-customer pattern to cut the blocking io time?

Comment: You could use [`CopyToAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `CopyTo` if you just want to make it wait asynchronouslly.

Comment: Or what should `<--process data block-->` be? Is this the encryption?

Comment: @Ackdari the actual data process is decrypting small data blocks, decompressing, then hashing, I used md5 hashing in the example to simplify the question,  and the actual read steam is much slower, it needs to parse another stream block by block. Performance profiler tells that 90% of the time is wasted on IO in the above example.

Comment: I would suggest to use either [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) or Task Parallel Library's [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) in order to properly separate read, process and write logic and then link them together.

Comment: If you want keep the UI responsive, you could just enclose the whole operation in a `Task.Run`. Trying to do it genuinely asynchronous will result in worse performance, and will still not be 100% asynchronous (the current thread will be blocked quite a lot). Asynchronous filesystem I/O operations are not well implemented in Windows.

Comment: Do you mean async streams from C# 8?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I was asking for async streams from C# 8, now I see other options like Channels and Dataflow, does async stream provide an elegant solution?

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you, I will take a good look at Channels and Dataflow.

Comment: Side note, they copied all the buffering logic from `BufferedStream` into `FileStream` years ago. It *shouldn't* \* be necessary to wrap `FileStream` in a `BufferedStream`

Comment: Also note, `hasher` is also disposable. It should be in a `using`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var query =
    Observable.Using(() => new FileStream(@"filePath", FileMode.Open), readStream =>
    Observable.Using(() => new BufferedStream(readStream), readBs =>
    Observable.Using(() => MD5.Create(), hasher =>
    Observable.Using(() => new CryptoStream(readBs, hasher, CryptoStreamMode.Read), md5HashStream =>
    Observable.Using(() => File.OpenWrite(@"destPath"), writeStream => Observable.Using(() => new BufferedStream(writeStream), writeBs =>
    Observable.FromAsync(() => md5HashStream.CopyToAsync(writeBs))))))));

query.Wait(); // or await query;
```

I consistently get results 2x to 5x times faster than your original code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` methods of the streams to await the io operations and read some fixed `blockSize` number of bytes into a buffer. However since `ReadAsync` may read less bytes as wanted, you need to makesure to read `blockSize` bytes in with a loop.

```cs
int blockSize = 1024;

using (FileStream readStream = new FileStream("filePath", FileMode.Open))
using (BufferedStream readBs = new BufferedStream(readStream ))
using (FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite("destPath"))
using (BufferedStream writeBs = new BufferedStream(writeStream))
{
    int offset;
    var buffer = new byte[blockSize];
    do {
        offset = 0;
        while (offset < buffer.Length) 
        { // make sure to read blockSize bytes
            var bytesRead = await readBs.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset);
            if (bytesRead == 0) break;
            offset += bytesRead;
        }

        if (offset > 0) 
        {
            var result = DoSomethingWithData(buffer, offset); // assumtion: retuns a new byte[] with only relevant data

            await writeBs.WriteAsync(result, 0, result.Length);
        }
    } while (0 < offset);
}
```

Comment: What is `DoSomethingWithData`?

Comment: This is way slower than the OP's synchronous method. My measurement was that it was 2.5x slower.